# streaming md5sum of contents of a large remote tarball

Tags: python

I need to fetch a .tar.gz archive from an HTTP server and perform an MD5sum of each file it contains.
Since the archive is 4.5GB compressed, 12GB decompressed, I'd like to do so without touching the hard drive. Of course I can't keep everything in RAM either.

I'm trying to use python for it, but my problem is that for some weird reason the tarfile module tries to seek() to the end of the input file handle - which is something that you can't do with piped streams. Ideas?

```
import tarfile
import hashlib
import subprocess
URL = 'http://myhost/myfile.tar.gz'

url_fh = subprocess.Popen('curl %s | gzip -cd' % URL, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tar_fh = tarfile.open(mode='r', fileobj=url_fh.stdout)
for tar_info in tar_fh:
    content_fh = tar_fh.extractfile(tar_info)
    print hashlib.md5(content_fh.read()).hexdigest(), tar_info.name
tar_fh.close()
```

The above fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gzip_pipe.py", line 13, in <module>
    tar_fh = tarfile.open(mode='r', fileobj=url_fh.stdout)
  File "/algo/algos2dev4/AlgoOne-EC/third-party-apps/python/lib/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 1644, in open
    saved_pos = fileobj.tell()
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

Comment: *for some weird reason the tarfile module tries to seek() to the end of the input file handle*. It doesn't actually. But it does need to use seek to find the various records in the file object. And the error indicates that the `TarFile` object is merely trying to record the current read position so that the file object can be returned to its initial state if an error occurs.

Comment: @martijnPieters I don't get it, in bash `curl http://myhost/myfile.tar.gz | tar -xz` works without seeking to the end; isn't it possible to replicate the same thing in Python?

Comment: In that case the `tar` command creates a local buffer on disk, IIRC. The Python tar module is not equipped for that use-case, no.

Comment: curl | tar -xz does not need to wait for the 5GB file to finish downloading before it starts decompressing it into individual files...

Comment: Yes, sure. But that doesn't mean it won't use a local buffer.

Comment: The title implies a specific implementation (with an external tar process, mkfifo-based pipes, etc), whereas the actual question doesn't deal with that (and, rather, does something far saner / more reasonable). I wonder how much room there is to retain the statement of intent while losing that implication...

Comment: BTW, the implementation given is open to shell injection bugs -- if given a maliciously formed URL, it could run arbitrary shell commands (think of `http://example.com/$(rm -rf /)`). Always safer to use individual `Popen` objects with `shell=False`, even if it's more work -- or, at minimum, to use `pipes.quote()` or `shlex.quote()` [on Python 3] to escape potentially untrusted data. JFSebastian's answer avoids the issue entirely.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah good point. My original implementation was indeed with urlopen but then I switched to POpen in an attempt to simplify the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find md5 sums of all files in a remote archive on-the-fly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile
import sys
import hashlib
from contextlib import closing
from functools import partial

try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError: # Python 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

def md5sum(file, bufsize=1<<15):
    d = hashlib.md5()
    for buf in iter(partial(file.read, bufsize), b''):
        d.update(buf)
    return d.hexdigest()

url = sys.argv[1] # url to download
with closing(urlopen(url)) as r, tarfile.open(fileobj=r, mode='r|*') as archive:
    for member in archive:
        if member.isreg(): # extract only regular files from the archive
            with closing(archive.extractfile(member)) as file:
                print("{name}\t{sum}".format(name=member.name, sum=md5sum(file)))
```