# Python hash module with one method to get the binary digest key

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I don't want to reinvent a module that perhaps already exist. But there is a fine example on [programiz](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/hash-file) that explain how to get the SHA-1 message digest

```
# Python rogram to find the SHA-1 message digest of a file

# import hashlib module
import hashlib

def hash_file(filename):
   """"This function returns the SHA-1 hash
   of the file passed into it"""

   # make a hash object
   h = hashlib.sha1()

   # open file for reading in binary mode
   with open(filename,'rb') as file:

       # loop till the end of the file
       chunk = 0
       while chunk != b'':
           # read only 1024 bytes at a time
           chunk = file.read(1024)
           h.update(chunk)

   # return the hex representation of digest
   return h.hexdigest()

message = hash_file("track1.mp3")
print(message)
```

Now I just created a `.py` that I import, but are wondering if such method already exist in the `hashlib` module or another well maintained module?

So I could just go

```
import some_hashlib_module
print some_hashlib_module.get_binary_SH1_digest("File of interest")
```

Comment: it may make sense to pass a file-like object to the function instead of a filename e.g., to [compute hashes for all files in a remote tarball](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27606823/4279).

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no ready-made function anywhere in the standard library to calculate the digest of a file object. The code you've shown is the best way to do this with Python.

Calculating file hashes is just not a task that comes up often enough to dedicate a function to. Plus there are many different types of streams where you'd want to treat the data slightly differently; when downloading data from a URL for example you may want to combine calculating the hash with writing the data to a file at the same time. As such the current API for handling hashes is as generic as it gets; set up the hash object, repeatedly feed it data, extract the hash.

The function you used can be written a little more compactly and support multiple hash algorithms:

```
import hashlib

def file_hash_hexhdigest(fname, hash='sha1', buffer=4096):
    hash = hashlib.new(hash)
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(buffer), b""):
            hash.update(chunk)
    return hash.hexdigest()
```

The above is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and code optimization